# Error 400 on adding new Excel worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Ideally, this macro would loop through a list of company names with a date range for each, and create a new tab with each company's information, but I am struggling to even create a new tab at the end of this macro, as it gives me an error 400.

```
Sub getStockPrices()

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim Symbol As String
Dim Interval As String
Dim qurl As String
Dim nQuery As Name
Dim LastRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets("data").Cells.Clear

Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

    StartDate = DataSheet.Range("startDate").Value
    EndDate = DataSheet.Range("endDate").Value
    Symbol = DataSheet.Range("ticker").Value
    Interval = DataSheet.Range("Interval").Value
    Sheets("data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

    qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & Symbol
    qurl = qurl & "&a=" & Month(StartDate) - 1 & "&b=" & Day(StartDate) & _
        "&c=" & Year(StartDate) & "&d=" & Month(EndDate) - 1 & "&e=" & _
        Day(EndDate) & "&f=" & Year(EndDate) & "&g=" & Interval & "&q=q&y=0&z=" & _
        Symbol & "&x=.csv"

QueryQuote:
    With Sheets("data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets("data").Range("a1"))
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    Sheets("data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("data").Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

     Sheets("data").Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 12

 End Sub
```

A picture of the sheet with the fields that starts the macro.

[image: And here's a picture of the sheet with the fields that starts the macro]

I put in the stock ticker, date range, and day or week price, and it calls on Yahoo and populates the "data" tab with this information. I have a situation where I need to run this for dozens of companies to analyze, but based on the way I have it set up now, I would have to create a new sheet each time and copy over the data.

How can I loop through a list of company ticker symbols and date ranges, runs this code, puts it in a new sheet and names the sheet whatever the company ticker is, and then moves on to the next company?

Or at minimum, how to create a new tab and name it the company ticker that was just run.

Comment: What line does the error 400 occur on when it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at this. This expects to find a sheet named Criteria with a named range call TickerList. This is a single column of stock symbols. StartDate, EndDate, and Interval are in the cells to the right of each symbol.

[image]

```
Sub getStockPrices()

    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CriteriaSheet As Worksheet
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim Interval As String
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim myCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set CriteriaSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Criteria")
    ' Iterate through the TickerList range
    ' creating a new sheet for each entry
    For Each myCell In CriteriaSheet.Range("TickerList")
        Symbol = myCell.Value
        StartDate = myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        EndDate = myCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Interval = myCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        With ThisWorkbook
            Set DataSheet = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            DataSheet.Name = Symbol
        End With
        qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & Symbol
        qurl = qurl & "&a=" & Month(StartDate) - 1 & "&b=" & Day(StartDate) & _
        "&c=" & Year(StartDate) & "&d=" & Month(EndDate) - 1 & "&e=" & _
        Day(EndDate) & "&f=" & Year(EndDate) & "&g=" & Interval & "&q=q&y=0&z=" & _
        Symbol & "&x=.csv"
        With Sheets(Symbol).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets(Symbol).Range("a1"))
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .SaveData = True
        End With

        Sheets(Symbol).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets(Symbol).Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

    Sheets(Symbol).Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 12
    Next myCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End Sub
```